# Flutter ListView and RefreshIndicator without scroll

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I have the following `RefreshIndicator` with `ListView` and I would like to use a pull-to-refresh gesture but without the scrolling of the list (i.e. the elements stay where they are. In a normal state the appbar will touch the system row).

[image]

This is the code

```
 RefreshIndicator(
      key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
      onRefresh: () => widget.refreshState(),
      color: Palette.primary,
      child: Container(child: 
          ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (c, i) {
                  var core = (widget.tabContent[selected] == null)
                      ? waitingWidget()
                      : widget.tabContent[selected];

                  var list = List<Widget>.from([
                    top,
                    core,
                    SizedBox(
                        height:
                        max(16.0, MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom))
                  ]);
                  return list[i];
                },
                itemCount: 3
           )
      ),
 );
```

Comment: If you really never want the list to scroll, you could place the listview and the refresh indicator into a `Stack()` so that the refresh indicator sits on top of the listview and it pulls down on an empty and transparent list.  But TBH, with your design you should just move the top bar above the refresh indicator so it stays still and the list can move and refresh freely.  Thats how 99% of apps appear

Comment: There would still be this color inconsistency and it would still scroll. I just realised this listview is not scrolling on Android

Answer (score 0):

Alex,

What I would do is create a Column that contains your header/`top` and your listview/`core`.  Basically move your header out of the listview, which would make it non scrollable, while the listview can remain scrollable and refreshable.

I'm assuming all the purple-blueish stuff in your picture is in `top`.  I've also turned `shrinkWrap` on for your listview as that might have to be the case depending on the content.  If you are getting errors, you can turn it off.

In the end you have a non-scrollable column that contains the header and content, and only the content portion is scrollable as a listview (including the refresh indicator).  This is the design most apps follow and will be familiar to your users

So something like this:

```
Column(
        children: [
          top, //Top has been moved out of the listview
          RefreshIndicator(
            key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
            onRefresh: () => widget.refreshState(),
            color: Palette.primary,
            child: Container(child:
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true, //I've set this as true here depending on what your listview content is
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),//This prevents scrolling, but may inhibit refresh indicator, remove as you need
                itemBuilder: (c, i) {
                  var core = (widget.tabContent[selected] == null)
                      ? waitingWidget()
                      : widget.tabContent[selected];

                  var list = List<Widget>.from([
                    core,
                    SizedBox(
                        height:
                        max(16.0, MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom))
                  ]);
                  return list[i];
                },
                itemCount: 3
            )
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
```